# How can I remove rows by name?

Tags: r, indexing

I am trying to split my data into test and trains set, see snapshot beneath:

```
      Happiness_score cooking.fuels.acces.per CO2.per.kg agri.empl.per F.agri.empl.per M.agri.empl.per service.empl.per GDP.PPP.constant GDP.PPP.current
IDN        5.399000                    67.1  0.5701778         33.04           32.61           33.31            51.63         2.62e+12        2.65e+12
BGD        4.694000                    18.3  0.3674927         43.46           64.01           35.73            20.61         6.85e+11        5.56e+11
PHL        5.073000                    42.2  0.3709298         29.19           18.96           35.92            71.04         7.45e+11        7.34e+11
IRN        5.365367                    96.6  1.5644309         18.03           22.82           17.15            53.38         1.15e+12        1.13e+12
JPN        5.987000                   100.0  0.2658084          3.63            3.22            3.94            82.31         5.14e+12        5.20e+12
IRQ        4.677000                    98.1  0.9725131         20.39           17.08           20.92            66.22         3.54e+11        3.47e+11
```

Simultaneously I try to remove the columns by names to make my trainset, but I am getting the following error message:

```
> train_data_PCA<-PCA_data_v2[-c('IDN','BGD','PHL','IRN','JPN','IRQ','ETH','ZAF','GBR','ESP','CAN','ARG','TLS','SLB','ECU'),]  
Error in -c("IDN", "BGD", "PHL", "IRN", "JPN", "IRQ", "ETH", "ZAF", "GBR",  : 
  invalid argument to unary operator
```

The issue is complicated because I had to imputate the data prior, but the function would not allow the to include a column with name variables and neither if I would factories the latter.  How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
row_names_to_drop = c('IDN', 'BGD', 'PHL', 'IRN', 'JPN', 'IRQ',
  'ETH', 'ZAF', 'GBR', 'ESP', 'CAN', 'ARG', 'TLS', 'SLB', 'ECU')

train_data_PCA = PCA_data_v2[!row.names(PCA_data_v2) %in% row_names_to_drop, ]
```